# Are there any sites where authors can offer up their novel manuscripts for sale to other authors (who may want to buy ghostwritten work)?

Tags: creative-writing, novel

Sometimes it is much easier for a writer to simply sell his/her completed novel to another author who is willing to buy ghostwritten novels. It usually has to do with preferring not to have to do marketing (by indie publishing) or simply not having the time to wait for responses from agents and so on (if traditional). There are indie authors out there who have established platforms and are open to buying ghostwritten work from novel writers. But are there sites where prospective ghostwriters can reach such people without simply asking around on facebook and other social media sites?

Comment: Why the hell did someone downvote the question? Am i not allowed to ask a question?

Comment: Yes that's not nice, especially without giving explanations. Maybe someone believed it's a little bit off-topic in regard to the usual questions, or it was too much original for them ^^ Anyway don't mind it doesnt bring a lot of consequences. You can still use bounty to bring more traffic to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure: do you want to write first and then try to find someone?

But ghostwriting is more about answering the need of someone, so it's the opposite.

What you are requesting is closer from traditional publishing than ghostwriting: I write and then I sell.

I don't see any platform doing what you request; if you're searching for freelance platforms for ghostwriters then try [Upwork](https://www.upwork.com/freelance-jobs/ghostwriting/) and those kinds of websites.

Comment: Traditional publishers take too long. You have to wait for several months.

Comment: Yes indeed but they have to go through a long process of editing, correcting, preparing the marketing part (if they do it), contacting libraries or online platforms and so on.
Otherwise you can always self-publish independantly, that's doable but you will have to do everything alone.

Comment: No, I meant it takes too long for these publishers to respond and finally pay an author for the book. That's why it's a lot faster to simply find another author who is willing to buy the book from you and sell it himself at a profit. I know that there are many authors who do that. I just don't know where they find these other authors that they sell them to.

Comment: Oh, I see. That could be a nice shortcut, but those published authors would not advertise the fact that they use ghostwriting.
But if there was a platform that was doing that anonymously it might interest them. That could be a business idea to produce such a platform ;)